# Pythonic method to evaluate averages over a huge data set

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector `X` that is composed of `N = 10e6` values. I would like to compute the mean for the increasing pairs. For example:

```
for i in range(0,N-1):
    Ex[i] = X[0:i+1].mean()
```

This is a terribly inefficient way of doing this. What would be a more intelligent algorithm for Python? Note `Ex` and `X` are both numpy arrays of float values.

Comment: You might have to write your own `mean` and pair it with something like `itertools.accumulate`

Comment: You could use `numpy.cumsum` and divide though by index.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `numpy`-centric solution could be as follows:

```
X = np.random.rand(10**6)
EX = np.cumsum(X) / np.arange(1, X.shape[0]+1)
```

Comment: You might want to use `float` array for division there : `np.arange(..).astype(float)` in case `X` is ints.

Comment: @Divakar because of Python 2 `/` floor division?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah that's the py2 thing. Or one can also use `numpy.true_divide()`.

Comment: `true_divide` is probably the most portable

Comment: This must be faster than my solution since it uses vectorial division. Not sure but would make sense.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I haven't tested it, but it will almost certainly be faster  especially for large numpy arrays.

Comment: if you avoid loops in python, it's always faster.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, numpy allows you to perform the looping in compiled C-code. Huge gains for large arrays when numpy overhead becomes insignificant.

Comment: `X.size` and `len(X)` also seem to work, does `X.shape[0]` have some advantage?

Answer (score 3):

not a `numpy` expert, but this avoids computing sum of elements every time. Just accumulate the sum:

```
current_sum = 0.0
for i in range(0,N-1):
    current_sum += X[i]
    Ex[i] = current_sum/(i+1)
```

Comment: This is already considerably faster and such an obvious solution. Thanks.